# On server works but after the publishing i get an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, application-pool

I have ASP.NET v3.5 website project. My project works at visual stduio on server.But after the publishing, i get error.

"Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_wkfb1ehc'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page."

i think this is an Application Pool problem but i don't know how to fix

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606919/odd-net-could-not-load-assembly-error    Might help.

Answer (score 0):

This is annoying since I have seen this before and I'm trying to recall how we fixed it.

One thing we did do we totally delete the contents of the site's `bin` folder on the server, then re-deployed. Basically when you compile your site's code, VS will generate these "App_Web_*" names for the DLL files and sometimes a new DLL file is compiled for a page code-behind, but an old DLL for that page is hanging around in the `bin` folder, which can cause the error you are seeing (at least I think that's was we thought the problem was :) )

Another thing you could do is to set fixed DLL namings for your project. Info on how to do that can be found here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992037(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992037%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). If you still get problems after changing that setting, then have a look at this SO question:

[ASP.NET WebForms Deployment - Setting the compiled \bin directory DLL names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837508/asp-net-webforms-deployment-setting-the-compiled-bin-directory-dll-names)